# cap_add and device options not working in docker stack file

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to start docker container on the rockpix node with cap_add and device options but docker stack errors  saying

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml vpnproxy
services.vpn_proxy.deploy Additional property cap_add is not allowed
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml vpnproxy
services.vpn_proxy.deploy Additional property device is not allowed
```

Below is my stack file.

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  vpn_proxy:
    image: ciasto/alpine-myvpn-proxy:v1
    volumes:
      - /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn
      - /etc/haproxy:/etc/haproxy
    networks:
      - vpn_proxy_frontend
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      cap_add: NET_ADMIN
      device: /dev/net/tun
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.hostname==rockpix"

networks:
  vpn_proxy_frontend:
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, `cap_add` and `devices` are ignored when deploying a stack in Swarm mode.  See the Notes section of the following links:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#cap_add-cap_drop
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#devices